# XmlCommandType Property missing from Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand

Tags: c#, oracle, powershell, odp.net

When writing a Powershell script, I loaded the ODP.NET DLL file and attempted to set the XmlCommandType Property on the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand class, but it states that the property is not found. Any ideas?

```html
#Load the Oracle DLL File
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll")


#After the Oracle Class has been loaded, Create the Oracle Connection
$oraConn = new-object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=192.168.1.1/DB;PASSWORD=pass;USER ID=user")

#Create and Configure Oracle Command
$oraComm = new-object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand("select * from USER.TABLE")
$oraComm.Connection = $oraConn
$oracomm.XmlCommandType = "Query"

#Open the Connection to Oracle and Execute the SQL
$oraConn.Open()
$oracleStream = $oraComm.ExecuteStream()
```

Comment: Any ideas? Yes; look at the documentation for the classes you're wanting to use. If you don't have documentation, contact whoever wrote the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Here is what happened. the Oracle Data Provider DLL, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll did not actually load from the file as this file was already in the GAC under the same version number. The fix was to manually replace "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess\v4.0_4.121.2.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll" with the updated Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll file. That then added the additional XmlCommandType Property to the OracleCommand Class.